# Why can't dismiss the viewcontroller in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview, uisearchcontroller, dismiss

In my app it has two views.in the first `ViewController` there is a `tableview`.when the first cell select from `tableview`, it loads another view with a another `tableview` with search option.then from the search result in the `tableview`,after I select a cell present view should dismiss.

- my first question is I can't select a cell direclty from the search result.I have to tap twice.
- my second question is cannot dimiss the `viewcontroller`

this is my code

```
- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController
{
    NSString *enteredString = searchController.searchBar.text;
    if ([enteredString length] >= 3) {
          [self getAirportCodesFromWebService:enteredString];
    }
    [self.airportTable reloadData];
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [airportArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    GetAirportTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"reuse" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    GetAirport *getAirports = [airportArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.AirportName.text = getAirports.AirportName;

    return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    GetAirport *getAirports = [airportArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *selectedAirport = getAirports.AirportName;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:selectedAirport forKey:@"selectedairport"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

I used `UISearchController` programmatically for searh.inside it I call for the webservice according to user inputs.help me with this

Comment: How did you come to this second view controller

Comment: drag the fisrt `cell` to the new controlle and select `show` for `Storyboard segue`

Comment: can you try modal..?

Comment: nope, got the point. that is because I didn't `Embeded` a `navigation controller`.thanx for your help @AnkitSrivastava

Comment: Embedding will require push and pop to achieve the functionality. or Modal with dismiss

Comment: yes, I kept same ''Show(e.g push)" storyboard segue.it works fine

Answer (score 4):

At first, in your second view controller you have a tableview with search bar.

- So this tableview have its own delegate & data source methods
  When you try to search for anything in search bar, search bar have its own tableview.
- This table have its own delegate & data source methods.

Hope your are distinguishing both tableview delegate & data source methods properly.

On selecting any cell from search tableview , You should call

```
[self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:YES];
```

this will dismiss your search results table view and you navigate to your controllers view.

Comment: I solved my two problems it before you put this, I told it is a good explanation only.thanx and I put a upvote for you.good work.thanx again.

Comment: Thank you so much!!